# What is the difference between EnableCorsAttribute and EnableCors

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api

While creating WebAPI project & fighting with CORS, I can use following 2 options

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:57137", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:57137", "*", "*")]
```

Can somebody please help me to understand why we have two similar methods ?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, when you name a class with a suffix of "Attribute", the compiler gives you a little syntactic sugar and allows you to omit the same when using the class.

In other words, they are exactly the same ie referencing the same class.